# How to give background-image for <h1> tag

Tags: html, css

I have tried something like this.But it did not work, Can any one kindly advise me how can I get that.

[image: Expected output].

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h1 class="pl-4" style="font-size: 200px;line-height: 2;background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/gradient-wallpaper-background_1159-5356.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg');">10+</h1>
    <h3>Years of Experience</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it can be done using SVG. I'm not sure you can do it using CSS only.

Comment: Never mind, it can be done. I found this: https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Answer (score 0):

Basically applying the CSS found [here](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/):

```css
h1 {
   color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h1 class="pl-4" style="font-size: 200px;line-height: 2;background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/gradient-wallpaper-background_1159-5356.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg');">10+</h1>
    <h3>Years of Experience</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the CSS-property `background-clip: text;` which can do this for you.
The browser support is not yet complete though and you will have to use prefixes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

```css
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, red, yellow, red, yellow, red);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi there</h1>
```

As an alternative you could go for an actual image or an SVG.